# ASP.Net MVC Unable to edit user because od the [Compare(Password)] in the class User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have table named Korisnik (on my language, on english its User) and i added an Edit ActionResult in my Controller , but it wont work because of the [Compare("Lozinka")] that is comparing the password from the database  and the added property PotvrdiLozinku, in other words i must enter the Confirm password in order to Submit the changes

```
namespace ProjekatFinalni.Models

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class Korisnik
{
    public int KorisnikID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Korisnicko ime:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Molimo vas unesite korisnicko ime.")]
    public string Korisnickoime { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Lozinka:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Molimo vas unesite lozinku.")]
    public string Lozinka { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Admin:")]
    public bool DaLiJeAdmin { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Gost:")]
    public bool Gost { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Pravo za unos:")]
    public bool PravoUnosa { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Potvrdi lozinku:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Lozinka",ErrorMessage ="Lozinke se ne poklapaju.")]
    public string PotvrdiLozinku { get; set; }



    public string LoginErrorPoruka { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Edit ActionResult in my controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            using (BazaProjekatEntities4 dbModel = new BazaProjekatEntities4())
            {
                return View(dbModel.Korisniks.Where(x => x.KorisnikID == id).FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id,Korisnik k)
        {
            try
            {
                using (BazaProjekatEntities4 dbModel = new BazaProjekatEntities4())
                {
                    dbModel.Entry(k).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Izlistaj");
             }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

And this is the Edit.cshtml

```
@model ProjekatFinalni.Models.Korisnik

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Korisnik</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.KorisnikID)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Korisnickoime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Korisnickoime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Korisnickoime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lozinka, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lozinka, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lozinka, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PotvrdiLozinku, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PotvrdiLozinku, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PotvrdiLozinku, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DaLiJeAdmin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DaLiJeAdmin)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DaLiJeAdmin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gost)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gost, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PravoUnosa, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PravoUnosa)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PravoUnosa, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Sacuvaj" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

[Only want to edit the permissions(Admin, Gost and PravoUnosa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvLom.png)

EDIT( Added the registration form that i used)

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DodajiliIzmeni(Korisnik korisnikmodel)
        {
            using (BazaProjekatEntities4 Modelkorisnik = new BazaProjekatEntities4())
            {
                if(Modelkorisnik.Korisniks.Any(x=> x.Korisnickoime == korisnikmodel.Korisnickoime))
                {
                    ViewBag.DuplicateMessage = "Korisnicko ime vec postoji.";
                    return View("DodajiliIzmeni", korisnikmodel);
                }
                Modelkorisnik.Korisniks.Add(korisnikmodel);
                Modelkorisnik.SaveChanges();
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Registracija je uspela";



            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
```

Comment: You should use a view model which has only properties you want required for this page.

Comment: Avoid using data model directly into view, just create another viewmodel class which reflects required properties and assign data model from viewmodel property values.

Comment: Thanks guys for the explanation , and for your time to view my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a view model specific for the view, which has the properties and validation attributes on them as needed by the view and use that to transfer data between your view and action method.

```
public class EditUserVm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Korisnicko ime:")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Admin:")]
    public bool Admin { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Gost:")]
    public bool Gost { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Pravo za unos:")]
    public bool PravoUnosa { get; set; }
}
```

Now you will use this view model for your GET and POST action methods. In your GET action method, first create an object of this view model, then get your `Korisniks` object for the Id passed in, Read and map the property values to the view model object and pass it to the view.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  using (var dbModel = new BazaProjekatEntities4())
  {
     var user = dbModel.Korisniks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.KorisnikID == id);
     // to do: If user is NULL, return a "Not found" view to user ?

     var vm = new EditUserVm { Id = id };
     vm.UserName = user.UserName;
     vm.Admin = user.Admin;
     vm.Gost = user.Gost;
     vm.PravoUnosa = user.PravoUnosa;
     return View(vm);
  }
}
```

Now makes sure your view is strongly typed to this view model because we are passing an object of the `EditUserVm` class to it.

```
@model YourNamespaceGoesHere.EditUserVm
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.Id)
  <label>@Model.UserName</label>

  @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Admin)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(a=>a.Admin)

  @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Gost)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(a=>a.Gost)

  @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.PravoUnosa)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(a=>a.PravoUnosa)

  <button type="submit" >Save</button>
}
```

Now you will use the same view model as the action method parameter. Inside the method, we will read again the User entity from the database and udpate only the field we want to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditUserVm model)
{
   var db = new BazaProjekatEntities4();
   var user = db.Korisniks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.KorisnikID == model.Id);
   // to do : Do a null check on user to be safe :)

   // Map the property values from view model to entity object
   user.Admin = model.Admin;
   user.Gost = model.Gost;
   user.PravoUnosa = model.PravoUnosa;

   db.Entry(k).State = EntityState.Modified;
   db.SaveChanges();

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**In short**, create a view model with properties absolutely needed by the view/ your code and use that to transfer data between your action method and view.

Comment: Yea i had this in mind but i didnt know how to how you said "Map the property values from view model to entity object" , so im very thankful for the full code explanation :), any ideas on how to reset a password for one user ?

Comment: Get the user object from DB for a specific userId , update the password property value and save!

Comment: Hm strange, im getting an error when i submit for the first problem, "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."

Comment: Catch the exception using the try-catch block, check the inner exception and you will be able to see which property is causing it.

Comment: Mhm, seems like the Potvrdi lozinku(Confirm password) property is causing the error, i dont understand why

Comment: You are reading the entity and updating only the 3 boolean fields and saving that entity back (without making any changes to other properties). In that case, you should not get that error. Put a breakpoint and verify all other properties have expected values before executing the SaveChanges method.

Comment: Yea they have changed before the savechanges

Comment: I think that this db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified, no mather if i only changed the 3 things i wanted is cheking props from Korisnik.cs , but in the database table i only have id , korisnickoime, admin, gost ,pravozaunos , i dont have the "Potvrdi lozinku"

Comment: How did you get the record saved in the first place if your `PotvrdiLozinku` is empty ?

Comment: I edited the post and put the Registration form that works, i created the "Potvrdi lozinku" prop  additional so i use it to compare it with Lozinka

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple and it could be from the start, i just need to add the user.PotvrdiLozinku = user.Lozinka; that will tell it that the Confirm password is equal to Password (For the [Compare]  that is in the User class.  :)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditUserVm model)
{
   var db = new BazaProjekatEntities4();
   var user = db.Korisniks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.KorisnikID == model.Id);
   // to do : Do a null check on user to be safe :)

   // Map the property values from view model to entity object
   user.Admin = model.Admin;
   user.PotvrdiLozinku = user.Lozinka;  // this line was missing
   user.Gost = model.Gost;
   user.PravoUnosa = model.PravoUnosa;

   db.Entry(k).State = EntityState.Modified;
   db.SaveChanges();

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```